# How to cast _variant_t to IXMLDOMDocumentPtr?

Tags: c++

There is a macro written in VBA, that I'd like to call from C++:

```
Public Function MacroName() As DOMDocument
```

I'm doing it like this:

```
_variant_t ret = d_pApp->Run(_bstr_t("MacroName")).bstrVal;
```

Now, I'd like to cast this ret to IXMLDOMDocumentPtr...

```
IXMLDOMDocumentPtr d_plDomDocument;
d_plDomDocument = static_cast<IXMLDOMDocumentPtr>(ret);
```

Well, that doesn't work. The error says, that the type is wrong.
What is the proper way to cast then?

Comment: I suspect that the `.bstrVal` returns a `BSTR`, not a `VARIANT`. But that implies `Run` already returns a variant. Something is going quite wrong there.

Comment: That is CORRECT! After removing .bstrVal it works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
_variant_t ret = d_pApp->Run(_bstr_t("MacroName"))>>>>>.bstrVal;<<<<
```

It should be:

```
_variant_t ret = d_pApp->Run(_bstr_t("MacroName"));
```

Once you do that you may find that your static_cast works - I cannot remember offhand. Otherwise, you can use the following method.

First `ret.ChangeType(VT_UNKNOWN)` then if that succeeds then use `d_plDomDocument = ret.punkVal;`. This will do a `QueryInterface` under the hood.

Or in a single step:

```
d_plDomDocument = IXMLDOMDocumentPtr(ret);
```

This will return a `NULL` `_com_ptr_t` if the variant cannot be converted to an object.

Comment: I get the same error, saying that the type is wrong. In first method, error occurs on line: ret.ChangeType(VT_UNKNOWN).

Comment: That means that the macro did not return an object.

Comment: OK I missed the error that @Msalters spotted! I have edited my post.